# Getting error trying to run `anchor test --skip-local-validator`

Tags: anchor

I try run this:

```
anchor test --skip-local-validator
Warning: cargo-build-bpf is deprecated. Please, use cargo-build-sbf
cargo-build-bpf child: /Users/nikiv/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin/cargo-build-sbf --arch bpf
error: no such command: `+bpf`

    Cargo does not handle `+toolchain` directives.
    Did you mean to invoke `cargo` through `rustup` instead?
```

And get error.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I removed rust installed with brew.

Then installed rust again via official curl installation.

Then it worked.